# jquery datetimepicker default no time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker

Is there a setting in jquery [datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) which means if I only select a date, then this displays only the date.

By default when you click on a date it displays: "18/09/2012 00:00"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `alwaysSetTime` option:

> Default: true - Always have a time set internally, even before user has chosen one.

```
$("input").datetimepicker({
    alwaysSetTime: false
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WP29E/219/

Comment: Above fiddle is not working and I tried the alwaysSetTime option which did not work on my machine

Comment: @AmmarCSE: The fiddle is out of date. This is *not* a question about the jQueryUI datepicker plugin, just to be clear. I've updated the fiddle, please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Sorry Andrew, I thought this was a question about timepicker.